# jScrollPane autoReinitialise

Tags: jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm struggling with reinitialise jScrollPane when content changes or is shown/hidden. 
Here's my [page](http://tinyurl.com/hs2g8pl) (I use jScrollPane only for Firefox) and here's my [code](http://tinyurl.com/jbvm36p) (see functions hideFooterSection and showFooterSection)

Basically if you click on "Disclaimer" the footer will expand and scrollPane is correctly working; if you click somewhere else and then you go back to disclaimer, no scrollbars are shown. I tried to destroy or renitialise the jScrollPane when the footer is collapsed but no way...any help?

Answer (score 0):

Reiniate jScrollPane as follow when any changes ooccur:

```
$('.Your Element Class').jScrollPane({
    verticalGutter :4,
    autoReinitialise :true, 
    contentWidth: '0px' ,
    autoReinitialiseDelay: 20
});
```

OR

```
$('#Your Element ID').jScrollPane({
    verticalGutter :4,
    autoReinitialise :true, 
    contentWidth: '0px' ,
    autoReinitialiseDelay: 20
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally used [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) plugin; it has been very easy to configure it and make it work.